# How to dynamically select storage option for models.FileField?

Tags: python, django, boto, django-storage

Depending on the file extension, I want the file to be stored in a specific AWS bucket. I tried passing a function to the `storage` option, similar to how `upload_to` is dynamically defined.

However, this doesn't give the desired results. In my template, when I try href to document.docfile.url, the link doesn't work.

Checking in the shell, this happens

```
Document.objects.all()[0].docfile.storage.bucket
 <Bucket: <function aws_bucket at 0x110672050>>

Document.objects.all()[0].docfile.storage.bucket_name
 <function myproject.myapp.models.aws_bucket>
```

Desired behaviour would be

```
Document.objects.all()[0].docfile.storage.bucket_name
 'asynch-uploader-txt'
Document.objects.all()[0].docfile.storage.bucket     
 <Bucket: asynch-uploader-txt>
```

This is my `models.py` file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

def upload_file_to(instance, filename):
    import os
    from django.utils.timezone import now
    filename_base, filename_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return 'files/%s_%s%s' % (
        filename_base,
        now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"),
        filename_ext.lower(),
    )

def aws_bucket(instance, filename):
    import os
    filename_base, filename_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return 'asynch-uploader-%s' %(filename_ext[1:])

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_file_to,storage=S3BotoStorage(bucket=aws_bucket))
```

Why is `aws_bucket` getting passed as a function and not a string, the way that `upload_file_to` is? How can I correct it?

Answer (score 2):

For what you're trying to do you may be better off making a custom storage backend and just overriding the various bits of S3BotoStorage. 
In particular if you make `bucket_name` a property you should be able to get the behavior you want.

*EDIT:*

To expand a bit on that, the [source](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/12ceed1dc822ce960e02176b6c7dce9f6e08a0e0/storages/backends/s3boto.py#L243) for `S3BotoStorage.__init__` has the `bucket` as an optional argument. Additionally [bucket](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/12ceed1dc822ce960e02176b6c7dce9f6e08a0e0/storages/backends/s3boto.py#L286) when it's used in the class is a `@param`, making it easy to override. The following code is untested, but should be enough to give you a starting point

```
class MyS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    @property
    def bucket(self):
        if self._filename.endswith('.jpg'):
            return self._get_or_create_bucket('SomeBucketName')
        else:
            return self._get_or_create_bucket('SomeSaneDefaultBucket')

    def _save(self, name, content):
        # This part might need some work to normalize the name and all...
        self._filename = name
        return super(MyS3BotoStorage, self)._save(name, content)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work. I need the bucket to be decided by the extension of filename, at runtime. If I make a new class that inherits from S3BotoStorage, won't I be required to pick a fixed bucket anyway, or run into the same problem?

Comment: I did [this](http://pastebin.com/raw/GQJ6ad72), but the same problem exists, i.e. docfile.bucket is assigned a function instead of a string value, and accessing docfile.url later gives an error, "Cannot concatenate str and function".

Comment: From what I can see of the source code, no you won't have to pick it when you initialize it. If you override the bucket property then you have access to all the instance variables. I think you'll have access to the file name at that point which will allow you to properly calculate which bucket you want to use. Either which way to take a look at the S3BotoStorage source code. You shouldn't have to override too many methods.

Comment: I took a look at the pastebin link that you posted up as well. You only override the init method there, and I don't think you'll even need to override that. Once I'm at my computer again I'll take another look at the source code and post up an edited answer

Comment: I think I can see what the intention is in the code snippet, but I still have some doubts. In the bucket method override, how would we have access to self._filename? When I used this, and then tried to access docile.url, the error I get is `'MyS3BotoStorage' object has no attribute '_filename'` on that line. Does this mean _save has not been run yet? How can I ensure that it does run before calling url?

Comment: Ah sounds like it. Might be worth overriding the `__init__` method just to make sure it's defined. Then put a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in there to debug exactly what code path is being taken to save the object and verify what bucket it's trying to connect to.