# How can I dynamically change the storage of Django FileField()?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-models

> *My question is not a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135556/dynamic-file-path-in-django) it is not related*

Basically I got the following model where some uploaded documents will be public and some others private. To decide when the doc is private or not, when creating the instance, I set the field `is_public=True/False`, then I will be able to choose the right direction within the **AWS S3 bucket**. So I want to be able to change the storage to `PrivateMediaStorage()` when `is_public=False`

```
from my_project.storage_backends import PrivateMediaStorage

class Document(models.Model):
    file            = models.FileField(upload_to="uploaded_documents/%d-%m-%Y")
    # file          = models.FileField(upload_to="uploaded_documents/%d-%m-%Y",
    #                 storage=PrivateMediaStorage())
    uploaded_by     = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,blank=True,null=True)
    nb_download     = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    is_public       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is the storage class in case it's important.

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage
from django.conf import settings

class PrivateMediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.AWS_PRIVATE_MEDIA_LOCATION
    default_acl = 'private'
    file_overwrite = False
    custom_domain = False
```

Comment: Are the public files also stored on s3?  Is it just a matter of changing the bucket?

Comment: yes! I have two different locations with `AWS_PRIVATE_MEDIA_LOCATION` and `AWS_PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION`

Comment: I don't have time to try things out and give a full answer, but can you use an extension of [this proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37061044/2715819)?

Comment: hmm, nevermind... that's not really runtime dynamic

Comment: yeah! I thought I could do something with it until I see the `self` in the class is the file, not the model instance

Comment: ooh: I think I have a way in.  Again I don't have time to really test it out, but if you use a dynamic filename generator in `upload_to`, you have access to the instance.  You might be able to insert a filename prefix, then override the storage `save` to pluck the filename and adjust storage variables accordingly?

Comment: thanks I will give it a try.

Comment: Hi, how did you finally go about it ?